# Complete the function that returns the entire chat messages

Tags: javascript

There is an open chat.

When a person enters the chat, the following message is displayed.
"[Nickname] came in."

When a person leaves the chat, the following message is displayed.
"[Nickname] has left."

There are two ways to change nicknames in a chat:
After leaving the chat, you can re-enter with the new nickname.
Change nickname in a chat.

When changing a nickname, the nickname of the previous messages displayed in the chat is also changed.

For example, if a person uses the nickname "Muzi" and "Prodo" in the chat in order, the following message is displayed in the chat.

"Muzi came in." "Prodo came in."

When “Muzi” leaves the room, the following message is left.
"Muzi came in." "Prodo came in." "Muzi has left."

When Muzi comes back in again with the new nickname, Prodo, the previous messages are changed to Prodo as follows.

"Prodo came in." "Prodo came in." "Prodo has left." "Prodo came in."

Since the chat allows duplicate nicknames, there are currently two people in the chat who use the nickname, Prodo. Now, when Prodo (the second person) changes his nickname to Ryan, the chat message is changed as follows.

"Prodo came in." "Ryan came in." "Prodo has left." "Prodo came in."

Limitations
Record is an array containing the following strings and its length is 1 ~ 100,000.

Here is a description of the string in the record.
- All users are separated by [user ID].
- [User ID] enters the chat with [Nickname] - "Enter [User ID] [Nickname]" (ex. "Enter uid1234 Muzi")
- [User ID] leaves the chat - "Leave [User ID]" (ex. "Leave uid1234")
- [User ID] changes nickname to [Nickname] - "Change [User ID] [Nickname]" (ex. "Change uid1234 Muzi")
- The first word is either Enter, Leave, or Change.
- Each word is separated by a space and consists of only uppercase letters, lowercase letters, and numbers.
- The user ID and nickname distinguish between uppercase and lowercase letters.
- The length of the user ID and nickname is 1 ~ 10.
- There is no wrong input such as an user who left the chat is changing their nickname.

Anyone can help me to solve this question? I’m new in programming javascript language

Comment: Input and output examples

record:
["Enter uid1234 Muzi", "Enter uid4567 Prodo", "Leave uid1234", "Enter uid1234 Prodo", "Change uid4567 Ryan"]

answer:
["Prodo came in.", "Ryan came in.", "Prodo has left.", "Prodo came in."]


Answer Code format
function solution(record) {
    var answer = [];
    return answer;
}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function solution(record) {
  let history = [];

  // looping
  record.forEach((item) => {
    const splitRecord = item.split(" ");

    const keyword = splitRecord[0];
    const uid = splitRecord[1];
    const name = splitRecord[2] ? splitRecord[2] : "";

    switch (keyword) {
      case "Enter":
        {
          // Check already left user with the uid, then change left user's nickName to new one
          const existUser = history.find((item) => item.user.uid === uid);
          if (existUser) {
            history = history.map((item) => {
              if (item.user.uid === uid) {
                return {
                  ...item,
                  user: {
                    uid,
                    name
                  },
                };
              }

              return item;
            });
          }

          // Then push new user to the rooms with the uid
          history.push({
            user: {
              uid,
              name
            },
            message: "came in",
          });
          break;
        }
      case "Leave":
        {
          // Check user, then make him leave from rooms
          const existIndex = history.findIndex((item) => item.user.uid === uid);
          if (existIndex > -1) {
            const name = history[existIndex].user.nickName;
            history.push({
              user: {
                uid,
                name
              },
              message: "has left",
            });
          }
          break;
        }
      case "Change":
        {
          // Change all user's nickName to new one with same uid
          history = history.map((item) => {
            if (item.user.uid === uid) {
              return {
                ...item,
                user: {
                  uid,
                  name
                },
              };
            }

            return item;
          });
          break;
        }
      default:
        break;
    }
  });

  return history.map((item) => `${item.user.name} ${item.message}`);
}

console.log(
  solution([
    "Enter uid1234 Muzi",
    "Change uid1234 Prodo",
    "Leave uid1234",
    "Enter uid1234 Ryan",
    "Leave uid1234",
  ])
);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.